# When Importing packages must the file name only be one word?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

When I'm importing packages/custom modules the import statement only accepts single word input.  I looked up the Packages info in the Python Docs and the example there only has one word imports. Are multi-word imports possible?

*This works:*

```
import Histogram
```

*But this doesn't:*

```
import File existence check
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the builtin [`__import__`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/functions.html?highlight=__import__#__import__), but it'd probably be better to not have spaces in the name.

```py
package = __import__("Name with spaces")
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use space when you want to name something. Use Camelcase like `FileExistenceCheck` or go with `File_existence_check`. I don't know if it would work just seen from the syntax but anyway you should not do it!